# Find declaration and definition of function using bash

Tags: bash

I am having a look af a big C++ project with more than 100 files. Given a certain function name, how can one find just using bash tools like find or grep, the declaration and the defintion of a function?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in the very simplest case,

```
grep -ER '^.*(.*);' file  #find declaration.
```

as for definition, its a bit tricky if you want to get the whole defintion. (ie. from opening braces to closing). you might want to show what you want to get by using a sample C++ file

Comment: Hi, could you please explain what you did in details, how to find a specific function name declaration? you answer is too difficult to understand.

Comment: it just says, grab everything from start till you find a "(" , then anything until it finds the ending brace ")" plus a semi-colon. That is only for the simplest case. Eg function name(int arg1);

Comment: I used this command in [Mono project](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) and it generated tons of results that I do not want.

Comment: Well, i did say its the simplest case. if you have a bigger problem to tackle, pls ask a new question and i am sure somebody will help you.

Answer (score 14):

Try [ack](http://betterthangrep.com), which is way better than grep. Color highlighting, the works...

```
$ ack funcion_name
```

Prints out all uses of function_name searching recursively through source files, it also is smart enough to ignore .svn and other metadata

Answer (score 5):

I believe that the most robust way is to use dedicated tools for this instead of using `grep`, `ack` or anything of that order. It is always possible definitions are spread over multiple lines in the most unimaginable way. The aforementioned tools will easily return the requested information for functions like:

```
int f(int a) { return 2; }
int g(a,b,c,d) int a,b,c,d; { return 2; }
```

but they will fail to give the complete value when your source is a bit more convoluted:

```
int f ( // declares a function
        // this function is going to be awesome      
        int a  // first variable
      ) { return 2; }
```

You problably should make use of `ctags`.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the convention that the function definition starts at the beginning of a line, then you can use:

```
find . -exec egrep '^fn' '{}' ';' >/dev/null -print
```

if you want to limit to headers, you can put -name *.h before the -exec

NB if you want to do this a lot, look at "tags" and friends fire keeping an up-to-date index which would be faster in future.

Answer (score 2):

I know the question is too old, I find @ghostdog74 answer very interesting, but he forgets to answer how to find the definition of the function.

Inspired from @ghostdog74 I think this could be the good method:

```
grep -Hnre '^.*fct_return.*fct_name.*(.*).*{
```

It just says, grab everything from start till you find the `fct_return` , then anything until it finds `fct_name`the opening brace "("  then anything until it finds the closing brace ")" then anything until it finds "{"